# Обращение к массиву класса C#

Tags: c#, массивы, классы

Есть класс:

```
class MyFirstClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int[] OOP { get; set; }
    public int[] arrayProgram { get; set; }
}
```

Есть текстовый файл:

```
9;44;32;95;84;72;89;12;34;88
7;32;61;45;90;53;87;22
```

В класс мы считываем информацию из файла в следующем методе:

```
MyFirstClasses = new List<StopInRoad>();
static void ReadData(out List<MyFirstClass> MyFirstClasses)
{
    MyFirstClasses= new List<MyFirstClass>();

    using (var sr = new StreamReader("../../file.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        string[] parts;

        line = sr.ReadLine(); // считываем новую строку 
        parts = line.Split(';'); // сплитим строку

        int countOOP = int.Parse(parts[0]); // количество элементов в int-овом массиве
        int[] oop = new int[countOOP]; // создаём новый массив с размером, который только что считали
        for (int i = 0; i < countOOP; i++) // пробегаем циклом по массиву, добавляя в него элементы строки по порядку, начиная со второго
        {
            oop[i] = int.Parse(parts[(i + 1)]); // добавляем в массив элементы строки по порядку, начиная со второго
        };

        line = sr.ReadLine(); // считываем новую строку
        parts = line.Split(';'); // сплитим строку

        int countProgram = int.Parse(parts[0]); // количество элементов в массиве arrayProgram
        int[] arrayProgram = new int[countProgram];
        for (int i = 0; i < countStops; i++) // пробегаем циклом по массиву, добавляя в него элементы строки по порядку, начиная со второго
        {
            arrayProgram[i] = int.Parse(parts[(i + 1)]); // добавляем в массив элементы строки по порядку, начиная со второго
        };
        var MyFirstClass = new MyFirstClass // переменной MyFirstClass присваиваем все значения класса MyFirstClass
        {
            Id = 1,
            OOP = oop,
            arrayProgram = arrayProgram
        };
        MyFirstClasses.Add(MyFirstClass); // добавляем все данные в List MyFirstClass       
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Вопросы:

- Как из метода Main и из другого метода обратиться к переменной Id и массиву OOP класса MyFirstClass по индексу?
- Как сделать метод, который вызывался бы из класса Main и выводил в консоль все элементы массивов по порядку?
- Создать метод, который будет находить сумму всех элементов массива до второго элемента. На вход массив с элементами, на выход найденная сумма типа int

Comment: MyFirstClass.Id и MyFirstClass.OOP[0] (1,2,3...) по второму вопросу используйте цикл foreach

Comment: А зачем вам свойство Id, если оно всё время единица?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не уверен, что вы именно эту логику хотели реализовать, но теме не менее вот что у меня получилось:

```
void Main()
{
    var data = ReadDataFromFile(@"C:\downloads\asdf123.txt");

    foreach (var element in data)
    {
        PrettyPrint(element);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

public void PrettyPrint(MyFirstClass element)
{
    Console.WriteLine("element id is {0}", element.Id);
    Console.WriteLine("oop:");
    foreach (var el in element.OOP)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(el);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("arrayProgram:");
    foreach (var el in element.arrayProgram)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(el);
    }
}

public static List<MyFirstClass> ReadDataFromFile(string filename)
{
    var result = new List<MyFirstClass>();

    var strings = File.ReadLines(filename);
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        var oop = ParseLine(sr.ReadLine());
        var arrayProgram = ParseLine(sr.ReadLine());

        var MyFirstClass = new MyFirstClass
        {
            Id = 1,
            OOP = oop,
            arrayProgram = arrayProgram
        };
        result.Add(MyFirstClass);
    }

    return result;
}

public static int[] ParseLine(string line)
{
    var parts = line.Split(';');

    int countOOP = int.Parse(parts[0]); //int countOOP = parts.Length - 1;
    int[] result = new int[countOOP];
    for (int i = 0; i < countOOP; i++)
    {
        result[i] = int.Parse(parts[(i + 1)]);
    };

    return result;
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class MyFirstClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int[] OOP { get; set; }
    public int[] arrayProgram { get; set; }
}
```

Повыше функция печати вашего списка (напрашивался массив MyFirstClass[] но оставил для наглядности как было.

Также вызывает вопросы необходимость расчёта countOOP - если мы знаем размер после split'а - и можем рассчитать. Представьте, что у вас весь файл бы из строк вида `44;32;95;84;72;89;12;34;88|32;61;45;90;53;87;22` - разве  не удобнее?

Не уверен, что в файле будет только две строки, напрашивалось прочитать весь файл в цикле.

Ну и разбил код на отдельные функции для облегчения понимания.

Update. Суммирование первых числе массива: классический способ и через linq:

```
// Вариант 1
public int Sum1(int[] arr, int count)
{
    var result = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
        result += arr[i];
    return result;  
}

// Вариант 2
public int Sum2(int[] arr, int count)
{
    return arr.Take(count).Sum();

}
```

Например

```
var oop = new[] {44, 32, 95, 84, 72, 89, 12, 34, 88};
var sum = Sum1(oop, 2);
```

выведет 76.

Comment: А если мне нужно посчитать все элементы массива до второго элемента?

Comment: Согласен, здесь удобнее использовать .Length. "До второго элемента" -
 значит написать цикл, который будет считать сумму элементов массива до второго

Comment: Добавил вопрос третьим пунктом. До второго элемента - частный случай, в общем мне нужно считать большее кол-во элементов. Про linq выражение не слышал

Comment: Как записывать параметры при вызове метода? Как прописать массив класса и count?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы в параметры передавался именно массив класса MyFirstClass